# Destroy tag 2003

Tags: support, status-completed

Up until a few moments ago there were three questions tagged [2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/2003). Now there are none. I can't image any reason to have tags consisting of just years, so can it please be destroyed?

Comment: With no questions it should disappear in a few hours I think?

Comment: Heh. Usually this is because someone entered "windows 2003" on the tag-line :P. We get to clean these up once in a while.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a good reason *not* to burninate [tag:2003] :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags with no questions get automagically culled.

As if by magic the [2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/2003) disappeared

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, otherwise I'd never even have brought this up.

Comment: I'm sure that if there were a manual it would be written in it ;).

Comment: @Iain This must be a Linux shop -- DOCUMENTATION IS FOR WIMPS!

Comment: @vortaq7, I'd argue that documentation is for users. It keeps them confused and busy long enough for us to get useful work done.